# Angular: set selected value for <select>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-forms

I have data set for my `<select>` loaded asynchronously. I use hot observable, as the data can change in time. The problem is I am unable to set selected value and also Angular does not point to first element by itself (there is no value set until user does it). I'm trying to subscribe to my own observable and... it doesn't work, I wonder why? How can I solve this problem?

PLNKR: https://plnkr.co/edit/uDmTSHq4naYGUjjhEe5Q

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
      <option *ngFor="let value of (values$ | async)"
              [value]="value">{{ value }}
      </option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public name: string;
  public selectedValue: string = '';
  public values$: Observable<Array<string>> = new Observable(observer => this.observer = observer);
  protected observer: Subscriber<Array<string>>;
  protected subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.values$.subscribe((values) => {
      console.log('never fired...');
      this.selectedValue = values[0];
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.observer.next(['some', 'test', 'data']);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You subscribe to your observable twice. Async pipe does it internally after your subscription.

When `subscribe` method is being executed it executes `subscribe` function

```
observer => this.observer = observer
```

and overrides `this.observer` property so it will have effect only for async pipe(last subscriber)

I would use `share` operator to solve it

```
new Observable(observer => this.observer = observer).share();
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/V5c5YxMuMGJPAFpNW4Di?p=preview)**

To see why `this.observer` is overrided just run this code

```
let myObserver;   

const observable$ = new Rx.Observable(function subscribe(observer) {
  console.log('subscribe function has been called');
  myObserver = observer;
}); 

observable$.subscribe(function next1() { console.log('next1'); });
observable$.subscribe(function next2() { console.log('next2'); });
observable$.subscribe(function next3() { console.log('next3'); });

myObserver.next();
```

[jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/jodizaz/2/edit?js,console)

As i mentioned early async pipe subscribes to observable internally

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L23

Comment: This is accurate answer +1, thanks for sharing tips Angular Star*

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, could you also give some more explanation about how the `async` pipe works overwriting the observer? I've thought it's safe to have multiple subscriptions till now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
[ngValue]="value"
```

instead of [value]

Assigned a value as

```
public selectedValue: string = 'test';
```

HTML should be changed as

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let value of values$ | async"
          [ngValue]="value">{{ value }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/12MidpvSKw67XmX9cwqS?p=preview)**

Comment: Please note that I don't know the initial value - the data is dynamic.

Comment: @DanielKucal from where you will get the dynamic value?

Comment: Let's say it comes from the server

Comment: still you can assign it to the variable `selectedValue`

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do in the subscription that is not even fired

Comment: why are you using `subscription`. Clearly explain how it works with service in realtime

Answer (score 1):

You should bind it to ngValue:

```
  <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
      <option *ngFor="let value of (values$ | async)"
              [ngValue]="selectedValue">{{ value }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I have just tested it in plunker and it worked. [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/UUVUNcaG996q38pN8gSo?p=preview)

Comment: It looks like working because you replaced real values with `selectedValue` and now the value is not set properly... [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/CE32tNcdfqnSiTG5SEzI)

Comment: You're right. There's something going on there when binding the <option> observable values to it - it does not fire. I'll a little bit hard to understand from the plunker, need to debug to understand this. When I bind it to static values, it is fired. [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/mBPiQouLa0L7ERJK8bF8?p=preview)