# Default value in input select Angular

Tags: html, angular

**libros.component.ts**

```
export class LibrosComponent implements OnInit {
          public order;
          ...
```

**libros.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="selectOrden">Ordenar</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm" #ordenar="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="order" name="ordenar" id="selectOrden" (change)="findOrder()">
              <option>Alfabético</option>
              <option>Fecha</option>
              <option>Valoración</option>
          </select>
 </div>
```

When the page is loaded this select is like this:

[image]
But I want a default value, like this:

[image: img01]
I also have tried with selected="selected", but it doesn't work here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: set selected value for <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122300/angular-set-selected-value-for-select)

Comment: @Jose you should not add "solved" in title, if an answer works for you, instead you should accept it (green check next to answer) see [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the field `order` with the value you want to display in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit()` method.